# How do I enable ZIP/TAR/BZ2 Download Buttons in my Mercurial HGWEB?

Tags: linux, mercurial, version-control

I recently got Mercurial running on my server, shared via Apache.  When I browse to the repos via the web, I see a list of my repositories with Atom/RSS links, but no download buttons.

My question is, how do enable the purple "ZIP", "TAR", "BZ2" download buttons (example: http://hg.pablotron.org/)?  I've been trying to find documentation for this, but must be looking in all the wrong places.

I am running Mercurial v1.6.3 on Ubuntu 10.04 with Apache 2.2.14. Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [hgrc manpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web), put the following in your configuration file:

```
[web]
allow_archive = bz2, gz, zip
```

Comment: Thx! Sometimes the obvious eludes...